# Is that OK to leave a small endless loop script running on server?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a small loop script like this, it basically just monitors a directory if there is a file called 000.txt created, it will call up another batch file to run then delete the 000.txt file and keep going like this.....

```
@ECHO OFF

REM Check if 000.txt exists

:LOOP    
IF NOT EXIST D:\data\000.txt GOTO SKIP

REM mklink if 000.txt exists...

call C:\ntfs3\mklink.bat

GOTO LOOP


:SKIP
REM Crafty 1 minute delay...

PING 1.1.1.1 -n 4 -w 600 >NUL

GOTO LOOP
```

So my question:

Is this a good idea to running a endless loop on server like forever to monitor a folder?

Comment: Does it have to run endlessly?  Could you run it every 5 minutes?   I would run it as a windows scheduled task.

Comment: I could set it up running every 5 mins, but user wont be able to see the changes right the way....so has to be like this

Comment: I don't see an issue with it.  Just make sure that it gets automatically run whenever the server reboots.

Comment: If the owner of the server says it's OK, it's OK.

Comment: The biggest danger is crashing without a chance to restart.  Perhaps not likely in this case but still possible.  Scheduled tasks are designed to prevent that problem.